# Collapsible Panel responsible to window scale

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to implement a responsive collapsible panel on my website. I saw that W3School have an example on the subject, however it was flawed. If you were to resize the window after pressing the button to expand/collapse, the panel wouldn't scale properly.

**EDIT:** Screenshots here:

[image: Default view]

[image: Minimised view]

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_collapsible_symbol) is their example:

**Code for collapsible**

```js
// Button Collapsible
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
    coll[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var content = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (content.style.maxHeight) { content.style.maxHeight = null; }
        else {
            content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
        }
    });
}
```

**CSS Code for affected panel**

```css
.aboutCollapsible {
    font: 16px/24px "Roboto";
    background: #202020;
    text-align: justify;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width: 580px;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 1px 20px 5px 20px;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.5s ease-out;
}
```

**My question:**
How would you be able to keep the "animation" of when the panel smoothly scrolls opens and allow still allow the panel fully respond to a window scale. *I do not wish to use bootstrap or anything other than HTML, CSS and JavaScript*

**What I tried:**
I tried to modify the value from pixels to percent. However, that didn't allow the animation to fully work.

Comment: Can you add a screensnap of the collapsible with flaw you mentioned? I couldn't find any issue with the example.

Comment: @Ms.Tamil unfortunately my reputation is to low for me to add any screensnaps. The way you can recreate it is to open the link, press any of the buttons to expand the panel. Drag one of the sliders to make the window smaller and notice how the text disappears as the window doesn't rescale to fit all the text.

Comment: You can capture the onresize event of window and execute the for loop inside the handler again.

Comment: @Ms.Tamil That sounds like a solution that could work, however, it would be easier to just make it scale to 100%. Is there a way to do that whilst keeping the "animation"?

Comment: @DaveJones, I have added screenshots of the problem for you which is pending peer review right now.

Comment: @AkshitMehra I have approved the edit, thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** This is not a perfect solution as it makes the collapsing animation too slow (it looks as if the animation is delayed), but still:

Update the code inside the `else` statement to `content.style.maxHeight = "1000px";`. A large enough height that you think your content will never attain.

**OLD:**

In your code, change this

```
else {
    content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
}
```

to

```
else {
    content.style.maxHeight = "initial";
}
```

and it works for me.

Comment: This solves the problem but causes another. The scroll in "animation" doesn't run.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a style

```
.active+.content {
    max-height: 150px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Change the max-height based on your requirement.